# Logging web services operations behind load balancer

Tags: c#, logging, load-balancing, log4net

I developed some web services will be installed on 4 different servers **behind a load balancer** mantains sessions.

I'm using c# and log4net.

The appenders are a RollingFileAppender and an AdoNetAppender.

I read from https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html (section **How do I get multiple process to log to the same file?**)

> If you use RollingFileAppender things become even worse as several
>   process may try to start rolling the log file concurrently.
>   RollingFileAppender completely ignores the locking model when rolling
>   files, rolling files is simply not compatible with this scenario.

I can't use RollingFileAppender with MinimalLock. But I want to log from the different servers to the same file.

I prefer to keep log4net but I'm interested also in other solution (not the linux syslog one). No commercial solutions allowed for costs.

Comment: I edited my post. Now maybe can be clearer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181762/discussion-between-emanuele-and-mason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'll discover that logging directly to the same file from multiple processes is not a very feasible option.

You have several alternatives:

- Log to different files - each server can have a separate file
- Send all your logs to one application, which will then log to the files. This will make your logging more brittle and require extra development effort.
- Log to a database - databases are designed to have multiple processes writing to them at once
- Log to a logging server - [Seq](https://getseq.net/), [Stackify Retrace](https://stackify.com/retrace/), and [Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-trace-logs) are some examples of solutions that are robust and designed to ingest logs from multiple applications - plus you get much better capabilities

Comment: Thank you for a clear answer; this was helpful to me. I am dealing with a similar need for a vendor product that happens to use Log4Net. In my own apps I use NLog, but I expect the answer is similar for both logging platforms.